# Does AWS Lambda actually log to any local sink other than console (and therefore CloudWatch)

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, seq

We're trying to attempt to force a local instance of an AWS Lambda function to log to Seq (or any other sink for that matter; but can't).

Does anyone know if this actually possible?

We have the target:

```json
{
        "Name": "Seq",
        "Args": {
          "serverUrl": "http://seq:5341",
          "apiKey": ""
        }
      }
```

But still no luck!

Comment: You will need to install your own logging libraries and configure the Lambda to use them. That will depend on the language that you're using, which you don't describe.

Answer (score 0):

Lambda is just a FAAS. You can deploy code into it that can log to anything that you would be able to log to from a EC2, it is just serverless. From your explanation it looks like you are looging to this URL - http://seq:5341. The Lambda must have access to this URL - but looking at it that does not look like a URL on the internet or a URL that I would expect in the VPC.